# Using T4 with SharePoint to generate aspx pages

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, sharepoint-2010, code-generation, t4

I tried using T4 to generate a aspx entry page for a SharePoint list, but T4 failed with an error message saying that the site doesn't exist (even though I'm sure it's there).

After investigating the problem I figured it was because we're using the Object model to access the list and we're not actually within SharePoint context.

what's the best practice for such scenario?
Should I use the new Client Object Model in SP 2010 or SP Web Services?

Answer (score 0):

With SharePoint 2010, I Used Client Object Model it worked perfect.